# RxJS, operator to apply an function on observable depending on it's position

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Let's say, I have observables X, Y and Z. Is there an RxJS operator, which apply actions depending on the position of every action, like that:

```
concat(x, y, z).pipe(someOperator(a, b, c)).subscribe(done);
```

so emitted value of `X` will be processed by `A`, value of `Y` will be processed by `B` and so on.

Comment: Based on your description, don't you actually want to `concat(x.pipe(map(a)), y.pipe(map(b)), z.pipe(map(c)))` then?

Comment: Not really. In worst case, it might help, but I'd like to produce less code like `concat(x.pipe(map(a)), y.pipe(map(b)), z.pipe(map(c)))`.

Comment: Are you saying that's not the result you want, or just that you don't want to write it like that? You're going to have to do it *upstream* of concatenation, because downstream you don't know which source a value came from.

Comment: I don't want to write it like that.

Comment: I don't think your problem is anything to do with RxJS, then; you just want to pair up observables with mapping functions, so I'd suggest reading up on array methods and what an ellipsis does if you need to handle an arbitrary number. It might be helpful to expand on *why* you don't want to write it like that, what the specific problem you want to solve is.

Comment: perhaps you should explain your constraints.  "I don't want to write it like that" suggests that maybe you have some other problem you are trying to solve that you are not expressing in your question.

Comment: @Brandon I just trying to figure out, how to make different backend requests  sequentially and process the responses with less code. The framework I'm using is Angular 7, and requests is not depending on each other.

Comment: if the requests are independent of each other, then you shouldn't be concatenating them.  `concat` imposes a specific ordering on the combined stream.  @jonrsharpe's comment is the answer to your question as written, but doesn't seem like your question matches the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You can possibily simply it like below, but to do it nicely you can create your own operator, if it's a frequent operation

```
from([{obs:z, fn:a},{obs:y, fn:b},{obs:z, fn:c}]).pipe(
mergeMap(({obs,fn})=>obs.pipe(map(value=>fn(value))
).subscribe();
```